# Page getting refreshed after getting the selected value from list element (<li>)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a below HTML structure :

```
<ol class="slds-progress__list" id="olid">
    <li class="slds-progress__item"> 123 </li>
    <li class="slds-progress__item"> 345 </li>
</ol>
```

I have written below Jquery to get selected li element and apply other class to it :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#olid li').click(function() {
            $(this).addClass("slds-is-active");
    });

})
```

Problem : 
The class `slds-is-active` is getting applied to the selected element but the page is getting refreshed and selection is getting disappeared.
How to avoid the page refresh here? Is there any other way to get the selected `li` element and apply a class and avoid page refresh.

Comment: does li have any link[as i am unable to see any link ther]

Comment: May be there will be other script as well as. Check that.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the Jquery code. There maybe any problem apart from the jquery code

Comment: With the code you have supplied, I see no reason for the page to refresh, please can you create a [MCVE] with code that demonstrates your problem.  If it is as everyone suspects and you have a link within your li, then you need to prevent the action of the link (see answers below)

Comment: @AlivetoDie There are no links.

Comment: @Pete There are no links.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#olid li").click(function() {
            $(this).addClass("slds-is-active");
            **return false;**
    });
```

Adding return false stopped the page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Returning false causes jQuery to not perform the default action when the event is being handled.

```
$('#olid li').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("slds-is-active");
        return false;
});
```

Looks like the default action for your element is to navigate to the selected link. Returning false prevents this behaviour.